# ConTeXt: Dynamically define macro using before/after options

Tags: macros, context, content-replication

## Background

Code generates a book's title and author within start/stop environments. I'd like to redefine the *content* from those environments as a macro that can be reused elsewhere. For example:

```
\startbooktitle

Famous Novel Title

\stopbooktitle
```

## Code

The following code (and countless variations of it) fails to create a macro named `BookTitle` with a value of `Famous Novel Title`:

```
  \definestartstop[booktitle][
    before={\define\BookTitle\bgroup},
    after={\egroup},
  ]
```

## Problem

Regardless of whether `bgroup`/`egroup` or `begingroup`/`endgroup` are used, the error is:

```
 ["lasttexerror"]="! Too many }'s",
```

Using `startbuffer` and `endbuffer` results in what looks like infinite recursion.

Dropping the `define` inside the `bgroups` compiles, but then the `\BookTitle` macro is not available elsewhere, and even if it were, the contents between `startbooktitle`/`stopbooktitle` would not be captured:

```
before={\bgroup\define\BookTitle},
```

## Question

How do you define a macro using the `before`/`after` options within a `definestartstop` command that captures the entire contents of the start/stop command when called?

In other words, how do you transcode:

```
\startbooktitle

Famous Novel Title

\stopbooktitle
```

into:

```
\define\BookTitle{Famous Novel Title}
```

Are there other possibilities that are preferable to `before`/`after`?

Comment: You can't do that with `\definestartstop`.  You have to use a delimited macro for that, i.e. `\unexpanded\def\startbooktitle#1\stopbooktitle{do something with #1}`.

Comment: `\unexpanded` is not strictly necessary but good practice to add if your command is not expandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro definition in TeX require explicit braces, i.e.

```
\def\foo{...}
```

Implicit braces like `\bgroup` and `\egroup` or any other token that was `\let` to `{` or `}` will not work.  The following is invalid

```
\def\foo\bgroup...\egroup
```

There are a couple of commands in TeX that allow implicit braces as delimiters, such as `\hbox` but `\def` is not one of them.  Since you cannot have unbalanced explicit braces in TeX (apart from a few `\halign` related hacks) you cannot grab the content of an environment from within `\definestartstop`.  However, TeX has your back and you can use a delimited macro for this purpose

```
\unexpanded\def\stopbooktitle{\stopbooktitle} % Don't expand me, I only delimit things
\unexpanded\def\startbooktitle#1\stopbooktitle{\define\BookTitle{#1}}

\starttext

\startbooktitle

Famous Novel Title

\stopbooktitle

\meaning\BookTitle

\stoptext
```

[image]

Unfortunately, as you can see this does not trim whitespace and the empty lines are converted to `\par` and the end-of-line character after the word “Title” is converted into a space.  You could now build some complex macro machinery with twisted expansion to remove these tokens, but since I am lazy I just do it in Lua.

```
\startluacode
```

```lua
function userdata.booktitle()
    local t = token.scan_toks()

    -- trim from the start
    for n = 1, #t do
        local cur_tok = t[n].cmdname 
        if cur_tok == "par_end" or cur_tok == "spacer" then
            table.remove(t, n)
        else
            break
        end
    end

    -- trim from the end
    for n = #t, 1, -1 do
        local cur_tok = t[n].cmdname 
        if cur_tok == "par_end" or cur_tok == "spacer" then
            table.remove(t, n)
        else
            break
        end
    end

    token.put_next(t)
end
```

```
\stopluacode

\unexpanded\def\stopbooktitle{\stopbooktitle} % Don't expand me, I only delimit things
\unexpanded\def\startbooktitle#1\stopbooktitle{%
  \expandafter\define\expandafter\BookTitle\expandafter{\ctxlua{userdata.booktitle()}{#1}}}

\starttext

\startbooktitle

Famous Novel Title

\stopbooktitle

\meaning\BookTitle

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: It's more common to use `\let\stopbooktitle\relax` and you can replace your Lua code in this case with `string.strip` which removes spaces at the begin and end.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster But will `string.strip` remove `\par`? At the point where I pass `#1` to Lua, the newlines have already been converted to `\par`.

Comment: Works here without problem for the example, to get rid of `\expandafter` I set the `\BookTitle` also with Lua: `\ctxlua{context.setvalue("BookTitle",string.strip("#1"))}`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Oh, but that will fully expand `#1` which might not be desired and can lead to errors if there is fragile stuff in `#1`.